# Drools render output in a webpage

Tags: java, drools

I'm new to `Drools Expert`, currently from the Sample project of the drools what I can only do is print something to the console. Now I integrate drools to a web project and It was successful, I was be able to print something to the console depending on the interaction of the user to the page.

**My rules currently is like this:**

```
rule "A test Rule"

    when
        m: FLTBean ( listeningScore == 1, test : listeningScore  )
    then
        System.out.println( test );

end
```

So what if I want to print it out to a web page? How would I do that? Do I need to use `return` to return some value back to the java page and render it to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display something on a web page, then you need to be using the API to invoke Drools and get some output, which can then be rendered by your web application.

Therefore, you need to consider how to get output from it within your Java code. There are a few ways of doing this.

For example, when performing a simple action such as validating a request, then just operate on the request which you insert. For instance:

```
rule "IBAN doesn't begin with a country ISO code."
    no-loop
when
    $req: IbanValidationRequest($iban:iban, $country:iban.substring(0, 2))
    not Country(isoCode == $country) from countryList
then
    $req.reject("The IBAN does not begin with a 2-character country code. '" + $country + "' is not a country.");
    update($req);
end
```

In that example, I'm calling a "reject" method on the fact which I inserted. That modifies the inserted fact, so that after rules execution, I have an object in my Java code, with a flag to indicate whether it was rejected or not. This method works well for stateless knowledge sessions. i.e.

1. Java code - Insert request fact via API
2. Drools rule - Modify the request fact (flag rejection, annotate, set properties, etc)
3. Java code - Look at the fact to see what was done to it

The following code example of how to perform this interaction is taken from the following full colass:

https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sctrcd/payments/validation/payment/RuleBasedPaymentValidator.java

```
// Create a new knowledge session from an existing knowledge base
StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
// Create a validation request
PaymentValidationRequest request = new PaymentValidationRequest(payment);
// A stateless session is executed with a collection of Objects, so we
// create that collection containing just our request. 
List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
facts.add(request);

// And execute the session with that request
ksession.execute(facts);

// At this point, rules such as that above should have been activated.
// The rules modify the original request fact, setting a flag to indicate 
// whether it is valid and adding annotations to indicate if/why not.
// They may have added annotations to the request, which we can now read.

FxPaymentValidationResult result = new FxPaymentValidationResult();
// Get the annotations that were added to the request by the rules.
result.addAnnotations(request.getAnnotations());

return result;
```

An alternative in a stateful session would be that rules could insert facts into working memory. After executing the rules, you can then query the session via the API and retrieve one or more result objects. You can get all facts in the session using the getObjects() method of the KnowledgeSession. To get facts with particular properties, there is also a getObjects(ObjectFilter) method. The project linked below has examples of using these methods in the KnowledgeEnvironment and DroolsUtil classes.

Alternatively, you could insert a service as a global variable. The rules could then invoke methods on that service.

For an example of how to use Drools within a web application, I knocked up this web site recently, which provides a REST API to invoke Drools rules and get responses.

https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web

If you have Maven installed, you should be able to try it out pretty quickly, and play around with the code.

Comment: I have a question about the link you gave me. I didn't set any `pom.xml` in my project because i don't know really what it does and if its necessary. And also about the option 3 you posted, how would I able to look at the facts using java code? Sorry for a really noob question.

Comment: A pom.xml defines the dependencies of the project. It's used by Maven, which uses it to determine what jars to download and bundle into the web project.

Comment: Added a bit of extra detail to the answer on how to query the session for facts.

Comment: @Steve the github project you gave is a bit big project for me to understand. Can you give a simple example of how would you insert request object in drools base on the sample you gave above of how you retrieve/modify it?

Comment: I have just added a little API code to show an example of this.

Comment: I've tried that concept from with in the java code calling the Drools instance and I get all of my rule System-out-println console code but when I try to print out something from the main method which called fireAllRules to see of anything was returned by a global variable I can't get anything to print. How does one do that?

Comment: Do you mean something like `ksession.setGlobal("myGlobal", myGlobal);` firing the rules and examining the value of `myGlobal` afterwards? That ought to work. It might be worth raising a question so you can show an example of the code which doesn't seem to be doing anything.